# WebService Async method question

Tags: c#

in playing around with the idea of using a webservice for my project I noticed that a couple of properties ( method/event ) were automatically created for me. I can see the purpose of the Completed event but I am not sure where the Async method would be used.

webmethod declaration:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloBrad()
    {
        return "Hello Brad";
    }
```

Consumption of service in codebehind

```
  localhost.Service1 service = new localhost.Service1();;
  service.HelloBradAsync
  service.HelloBradCompleted
  service.HelloBrad
```

could somebody please explain the usage of the HelloBradAsync method.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async methodology allows your code to continue executing while the server is processing the message.  Using your normal service.HelloBrad code, the thread will block until the webservices returns a response.

Instead, if you call HelloBradAsync, it immediately moves on to your next line of code.  When the server is done, it will respond inside the "HelloBradCompleted" event.

This is so that the webservice doesn't block your primary thread while it executes, and is definitely the proper way of doing business.  It might require a change in your programming paradigm, but you'll find the benefits outweigh the costs.

Comment: "..is definitely the proper way of doing business" I would have to disagree. it might make scene to use Async if you are invoking a service within the UI thread but there is no reason to do it if your are calling a service in a blocking call, for example another WebService.

Comment: @Keivan: That's a good point - if you need the return value before you can move to the next line of code, having a blocking webservice call is valuable.